# Kivy StringProperty to python string conversion

Tags: python, kivy

I am new to kivy and python.

I have, output=StringProperty('') and another string named 'text'.
Now I want to convert "output" to "text" and then perform further operations on normal python string.

"output" and "text" are in two different classes.

Please help me for this conversion.I tried all possible solutions that I know, but I always get either "AttributeError" or "NameError".

Thank you in advance.

Here is the code part

Here is the "output" string -

```
class RecordButton(Button):
# String Property to Hold output for publishing by Textinput
output = StringProperty('')
def record(self):
    # GUI Blocking Audio Capture
    with m as source:
        audio = r.listen(source)

    try:
        # recognize speech using Google Speech Recognition
        value = r.recognize_google(audio)
        self.output = "You said \"{}\"".format(value)

    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        self.output = ("Oops! Didn't catch that")

    except sr.RequestError as e:
        self.output = ("Uh oh! Couldn't request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))
```

And here is the "original_text" string -

```
def main(self):
    """main function"""
    original_text =????????
    if len(original_text) > 600:
        print("You can't check more than 600 characters at a time.")
        quit()
    fixed_text = original_text
    results = GrammarButton.get_ginger_result(self,original_text)

    # Correct grammar
    if(not results["LightGingerTheTextResult"]):
        print("Good English :)")
        quit()
```

Comment: can we see your code, please. or where, in your code, the problem is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an ***ObjectProperty*** to hook up to your *class RecordButton*, and you can reference it in *class Main*. Please refer to the small example below for details.

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ObjectProperty


class OutputKivyStringProperty(BoxLayout):
    output = StringProperty('Kivy StringProperty')


class RootWidget(BoxLayout):
    output_obj = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RootWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        output_obj = OutputKivyStringProperty()
        text = output_obj.output
        print("text={}".format(text))


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

## Output

[image: Img01]